# Google Maps Engine - This resource is too large to be accessed via this API call

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-engine

We have Google Maps Engine account. I recently uploaded a shape file which has approximately 179,000 features.

Find below the exact stats for the Table

- Feature count: 178956
- Bad feature count: 0
- Vertex count: 4817776
- Polygon count: 179058
- Multi-polygon count: 102

I am trying to perform an intersect query as following

"https://www.googleapis.com/mapsengine/v1/tables/{tableid}/features?where=ST_INTERSECTS(geometry,ST_POINT(55.300153,25.256426))"

But it throws the following error

```
error: {errors: [{domain: "usageLimits",reason: "limitExceeded",message: "This resource is too large to be accessed via this API call."}],code: 403,message: "This resource is too large to be accessed via this API call."}
```

To make sure if I am using the OAuth correctly, I change the tableID and perform the same query on another table which has 1500 records, and I get the proper results.

Questions

1. If I have properly generated Access Token using Google OAuth Client, do I still need the API Key to access the private table?
2. Does Google Maps Engine supports query for features in table with records greater than 100K? 
   I have read the Google documentation for this error and Maps Engine limitations at following URL [[https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/limits][1]](https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/limits%5d%5b1%5d) . It says that Dynamic capacity for feature requests if greater than 100K is not supported. Is this limit applicable only for query per second (QPS) or any request?
3. Any suggestions to use intersect query for high volume of GIS data ?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

1. No.  The API key is only used to access public tables.
2. GME API limits are detailed at:
   https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/limits#capacity
3. Examples of how to use the intersects function can be found at:
   https://developers.google.com/maps-engine/documentation/read#geographic_restrictions

If there's something specifically that you need additional help with don't be afraid to raise a support case at:
http://google.com/enterprise/portal